# The first Activity is destroyed when pressing Back button from SecondActivity

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I'm implementing an Android app playing online Video and get the error. For the simplicity, I made an sample app here. There are 2 activities: MainActivity and SecondActivity.

```
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}

SecondActivity

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG = "SecondActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.e(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged");
    }
}

AndroidManifiest.xml    

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

In `MainActivity` has a button to start `SecondActivity`. My scenario is putting the device in landscape mode and click button to start `SecondActivity`(so that `SecondActivity` is auto rotated to landscape mode). Then pressing Back button immediately to return back `MainActivity`. But the `MainActivity` is destroyed. Here is my log:

```
12-11 22:22:20.940: E/MainActivity(400): onCreate
12-11 22:22:20.960: E/MainActivity(400): onStart
12-11 22:22:20.960: E/MainActivity(400): onResume
12-11 22:22:24.524: E/SecondActivity(400): onStart
12-11 22:22:24.524: E/SecondActivity(400): onResume
12-11 22:22:24.544: E/SecondActivity(400): onConfigurationChanged
12-11 22:22:24.634: E/MainActivity(400): onStop
12-11 22:22:24.634: E/MainActivity(400): onDestroy
12-11 22:22:34.133: E/SecondActivity(400): onStop
12-11 22:22:34.133: E/SecondActivity(400): onDestroy
```

The `MainActivity` is destroyed and the current activity is `SecondActivity`. If I press Back one more, the `SeconActivity` is destroyed.
Anyone can explain me why `MainActivity` is destroyed or this is error of Android OS.
Thanks in advance.
**P/S**: For this case happens, putting the device in landscape, then clicking button to start SecondActivity and press Back immediately.
The OTHER cases works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity is being recreated on rotation. To keep it from being recreated when the device rotates you'll need the same configChanges as the SecondActivity: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: Yes. This is what I did. But Could you explain me why MainActivity is recreated. Its orientation is already set portrait.

Comment: Even when locked to portrait, these activity lifecycle changes can be triggered if you don't add the configChanges to say you'll handle them manually.